# Need help identifying app state during phone call in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, notifications, ios14, callkit

I have an app that does a certain task.
While performing this task, the app also listens for when the user receives a phone call.
If the user receives a phone call, this task needs to be interrupted.

On iOS 13 we listen to `willResignActiveNotification` for when the incoming call and to `didBecomeActiveNotification` for when the call ends (this for when the user has the app open before the phone call).

On iOS 14 this also works if the call setting is set to **Full Screen**.
But when this setting is changed to **Banner** these notifications are never triggered.

I can't identify the app state for when the setting is set to **Banner**. My guess is that it is still in the active state.

The problem is that although the notifications are not called, the UI is interrupted as if the app was placed in the background when the user has the **Banner** setting on.

---

#### Note

I also conform to `CXCallObserverDelegate` and implement `callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall)` method to know when the user receives a call and when the call ends.
So a solution is to just resume the task when the call ends and this method is triggered.
But I want to understand the app lifecycle in this case which is not making sense to me.

---

#### Code Sample

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidEnterBackground(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    timer.resume()
    updateUI()
}
```

```swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    timer.invalidate()
    pauseUI()
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

```swift
@objc private func appDidEnterBackground(_ notification: Notification) {
    timer.invalidate()
    pauseUI()
}
    
@objc private func appWillEnterForeground(_ notification: Notification) {
    timer.resume()
    updateUI()
}
```

Comment: Are you using voip notifications?

Comment: No, I just conform to CXCallObserverDelegate which in turn will trigger `callChanged` method with information on the call state.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10 our app uses [`callObserver:callChanged:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallobserverdelegate/1649009-callobserver?language=objc) from `CXCallObserverDelegate` to detect incoming or answered phone calls like:

```
@import CallKit;

@property (nonatomic) CXCallObserver *callObserver;

#pragma mark - Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Register Call Observer to detect incoming calls:
    _callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
    [_callObserver setDelegate:self
                         queue:nil];
}

#pragma mark - CXCallObserverDelegate

- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    // Based on state:
    if (call.hasEnded) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallObserver: Call has ended");
    }
    else if (call.hasConnected) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallObserver: Call has connected");
    }
    else if (!call.isOutgoing && !call.hasConnected && !call.hasEnded) {
        NSLog(@"CXCallObserver: Call is incoming");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"CXCallObserver: None of the conditions");
    }
}
```

Since the default behaviour on iOS 14 is to show a banner for incoming calls, we indeed saw that `CXCallObserverDelegate` was not called anymore.

When we changed the Phone setting in the iOS app to **Full Screen** it did work again. Obviously, just like in iOS 13 and before.

However, when we flipped the setting back to **Banner**, our app did call `CXCallObserverDelegate` event on an incoming banner call.

Based on the numerous issues with [Local Network permission](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660485) in iOS 14, it's only an estimated guess that here a similar root cause applies, where settings are only handed over to the native functionality once actively set by the user, and not on a default system setting.

I hope that explicitly changing the setting will solve your issue, or that we were accidentally lucky.

Note: the observations are done on iPhone SE 2nd gen with iOS 14.6.